# How do I apply timeout and retry decorator functions to google-cloud-storage client in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, python-decorators

I want to alter the default timeout and retries for Google Cloud Storage requests and can see there are decorator functions in the google cloud package in the api_core directory, how do I apply these to the storage client (if that is the right term)?

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.api_core import timeout

timeout_ = timeout.ConstantTimeout(timeout=600)
storage_client = storage.Client()
storage_client.get_bucket(name_of_bucket)
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/timeout.html) shows that these decorators are designed to work with functions that take a timeout parameter, which the GCS SDK functions do not.  I am a bit surprised to not see any obvious way to configure timeouts with the storage SDK, short of perhaps creating a custom HTTP client via the `_http` parameter to the `Client` constructor, which doesn't appear to have long term support :(

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a custom solution based on the api_core folder. The difference resides in the func_with_timeout function. In this way it configures the specified timeout and the number of retries for the function you are wrapping.

```
import functools
import signal
from multiprocessing import TimeoutError

import six
from google.cloud import storage


_PARTIAL_VALID_ASSIGNMENTS = ("__doc__",)


def wraps(wrapped):
    """A functools.wraps helper that handles partial objects on Python 2."""
    # https://github.com/google/pytype/issues/322
    if isinstance(wrapped, functools.partial):  # pytype: disable=wrong-arg-types
        return six.wraps(wrapped, assigned=_PARTIAL_VALID_ASSIGNMENTS)
    else:
        return six.wraps(wrapped)


def raise_timeout(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutError


@six.python_2_unicode_compatible
class ConstantTimeout(object):
    """A decorator that adds a constant timeout argument.

    This is effectively equivalent to
    ``functools.partial(func, timeout=timeout)``.

    Args:
        timeout (Optional[float]): the timeout (in seconds) to applied to the
            wrapped function. If `None`, the target function is expected to
            never timeout.
    """

    def __init__(self, timeout=None, retries=None):
        self._timeout = timeout
        self._retries = retries

    def __call__(self, func):
        """Apply the timeout decorator.

        Args:
            func (Callable): The function to apply the timeout argument to.
                This function must accept a timeout keyword argument.

        Returns:
            Callable: The wrapped function.
        """

        @wraps(func)
        def func_with_timeout(*args, **kwargs):
            """Wrapped function that adds timeout."""
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, raise_timeout)

            i = 1
            while i <= self._retries:
                try:
                    # Schedule the signal to be sent after ``time``.
                    signal.alarm(self._timeout)
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)

                except TimeoutError:
                    i += 1
                    pass

            return TimeoutError("Exceed maximum amount of retries: {}".format(self._retries))

        return func_with_timeout

    def __str__(self):
        return "<ConstantTimeout timeout={:.1f}>".format(self._timeout)
```

Then you just have to create a new function passing the one you want to wrap as an argument to the timeout_ decorator:

```
timeout_ = ConstantTimeout(timeout=2, retries=3)
storage_client = storage.Client()
get_bucket_with_timeout = timeout_(storage_client.get_bucket)
buck = get_bucket_with_timeout(name_of_bucket)
print(buck)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the timeout in seconds as a second parameter:

```
storage_client.get_bucket(name_of_bucket,120)
```